# Does Windows XP work on a modern laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, laptop

I want to buy a new Dell laptop, but it ships with Windows 8 or Windows 10.

Can I take a Core i3 or Core i5 Dell laptop and install Windows XP on it?

Comment: You likely could, but drivers will be a pain, and why anyway, That's a terrible idea.

Comment: Easier solution is purchase any laptop that support virtualization and the install XP on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 6):

> please suggest me a well new laptop which will support windows xp 32 bit.

Hardware recommendations are off-topic on SuperUSer.

A bigger problem though are drivers. Many (most?) manufacturers no longer write drivers for XP. That means running in VGA mode (640x460@16 colours) if it works at all. Likely no USB drivers, possible no HDD access...

What you can do is install a modern OS on it and use virtualisation software like vmware player to run XP in a window. This will allow you to specifcy which hardware gets 'seen' by your XP guest.

This also help you make sure that the XP guest does not have access to any network or USB ports. (OLD OLD OLD OS. No regular security updates. Original planned end of life in 2009! Do not connect to any network!).

Comment: +1 for "make sure that the XP guest does not have access to any network or USB ports".